# Android Edit Text Set Error message appears over Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Upon a validation error for an edit text I use the set error function to display a message to the user why their input was wrong.

If the error message is showing, and the user opens the navigation drawer, the error message displays on top of the nav drawer.

Any ideas on how to have the error message display behind the nav drawer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One quick and dirty solution which seems to have resolved the issue was to have the nav draw call request focus upon opening, hence removing the pop up error message from the edit text (as it looses focus), however the error icon in the edit text remained.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have had same issue. I came up with following solution in your mainactivity (which have navigation drawer) add following code

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if ( v instanceof EditText) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY())) {
                v.clearFocus();
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```